# Jenkins build failed due to mv cmd in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, build

I am using Docker build file. I have given the mv command and arguments to it. Still it fails due to mv: missing destination file operand after './npmrc'

The ARG npm_userconfig_path is provided in the jenkins-master.xml

What am I missing here ??

```
    <buildAdditionalArgs>--build-arg npm_userconfig_path=__temp_config/.npmrc</buildAdditionalArgs>


# FROM kumo-docker-release-local.artylab.expedia.biz/library/runtime-team-logo:latest
FROM kumorelease-docker-virtual.artylab.expedia.biz/stratus/app-node:12-slim
# FROM node:12.14-alpine AS build

# When the client Dockerfile builds, copy all of its source code into the new image's /app WORKDIR
WORKDIR /app-build
RUN useradd -ms /bin/sh admin
COPY --chown=admin . .
RUN chown -R admin .
USER root

# Display the copied files and directories in the build output for any troubleshooting
RUN du -sh .[!.]* *| sort -nr


# Use provided value from build for the user level .npmrc and copy to user home directory
ARG npm_userconfig_path
RUN mv $npm_userconfig_path ~/.npmrc

# Verify in the build output that the provided .npmrc exists and is picked up by npm
# RUN ls -lh ~/.npmrc
# RUN npm config ls

# FROM node:12.14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# When the client Dockerfile builds, install all of the app dependencies
# RUN npm install

# Perform a prod build
# RUN ng serve

# FROM kumo-docker-release-local.artylab.expedia.biz/library/runtime-team-logo:latest
# COPY --from=intermediate /usr/src/app /app/


### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/metrics-service-ui /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443
CMD [ "ng", "serve" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
mv: missing destination file operand after './npmrc'
```

would match if your line

```
RUN mv $npm_userconfig_path ~/.npmrc
```

is executed as

```
RUN mv ~/.npmrc
```

which would indicate for some reason the variable has no value. This somehow puts to question whether your docker command line looked like

```
docker build --build-arg npm_userconfig_path=__temp_config/.npmrc .
```

Therefore I suggest you check how exactly Jenkins is invoking docker. If necessary turn up logging. My pure guess is that you are missing the additional dot, and a solution could be to use

```
<buildAdditionalArgs>--build-arg npm_userconfig_path=__temp_config/.npmrc .</buildAdditionalArgs>
```